# Merging docs on SVN without opening it in MS Office editor

Tags: svn, merge, ms-word, tortoisesvn, docx

I have a docx file in my SVN repository. Now I want different users make changes to it and I want `to merge all the changes applied on it (assume there is no conflict) without opening the docx file.` I have tried with Tortoise SVN which opens the MS Office review option for that but my application will be a client based one and I do not want to force my client to install MS Office so **is there any way to merge changes to a docx file without use of MS Office (if no conflict is there)?** In case of conflicts we may allow to edit it by opening file in OpenOffice or other open source editor rather that MS Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by zerkms docx in fact is a binary (zipped directory, to be completely precise) file so I researched for some time and got the hint that by following we can achieve it using XML-aware merge tool.

- convert docx extention to zip
- unzip the file
- save this file/folder in subversion
- this folder will contain many xml files
- using XML aware merging tool we can merge in xml file
- zip the modified folder
- change the extension to docx

I will definately find time to implement this and post result over here.

Comment: Eight years after, it should be clear the accepted answer was not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

`docx` in fact is a **binary** (zipped directory, to be completely precise) file, so you cannot merge it

Comment: thanx for reply. there are some review and change options in msoffice that shows differences can we do such things using comand prompt without using ms-office?

Comment: I don't know, I'm very lame in MS Office, sorry ;-)

Comment: Not so.  Being a binary by compression is irrelevant; it the XML is sane enough, there should be a way of merging.

Comment: @Leandro SVN is unaware of its internal format, for SVN it's a blob. You don't have semantic merging for arbitrary blobs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Flat OPC XML format (accessed via "Save As" in Word), in which non-conflicting changes could be merged, but you would need an XML-aware merge tool.

Even then, some changes resulting in well-formed and valid XML, may mean the file will no longer open in Word. Are you prepared to manually fix the file when this happens?

If your users restrict themselves to paragraphs and simple tables (and you find your XML aware merge tool), you might be able to stay out of trouble.

Comment: i have tried using the tortois svn for merge but it opens the doc in words review option where i can accept or reject change but i dont want the user need to install msoffice. i have tried command line when i use `svn diff` for text file it shows the changes but in case of docx it says Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
svn:mime-type = application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

The XML file formats supported by MS Office (.xml, .docx &c) are not mergeable, as they have complex internal structures.  Worse, MS Office 2010 and later have defaulted to zipped DOCX, without a flat version (LibreOffice has FODT and the such, which is not zipped and can be diffed).

The MS Office 2007 and before .xml files are flat, but they are different from the XML format behind the deceptively named MS OpenXML supported by MS Office 2010 and later; so, while it can be diffed and thus can be used to alleviate the usage of storage space in version control servers, it still is not fit for merging, and is obsolete since MS Office 2010.